# Enable asp.net core request validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Am I missing something or asp.net core allows to post script tag in user text fields? In Previous versions of asp.net mvc I needed to allow it by [AllowHtml] attribute.

Is there a way how enable validation agains potentially dangerous values?

I'm free to submit value like

```
<script src='http://test.com/hack.js'></script>
```

during form post.

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new TestModel { Content = "Test" };
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(TestModel model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);

            return Content("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TestModel

<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <label asp-for="Content">Content<strong>*</strong></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Content"></span>
        <input asp-for="Content" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't hit that problem yet. Everything in ASP.NET Core is opt-in so I'm pretty sure you'd need to add it as middleware but I'm not sure that's been ported across yet. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: In System.Web there's a class called `System.Web.CrossSiteScriptingValidation` which seems to hold the logic for determining if the request is invalid. Looks simple enough from a quick glance. Maybe that could be used to knock up some middleware if something doesn't already exist.

Comment: It seems that perhaps requestvalidation was removed because we should not depend on it for security, instead we should validate input and encode untrusted output http://forums.asp.net/t/2032496.aspx?Where+is+AllowHtml

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ASP.NET Core does not have a feature similar to [Request validation](https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation), as Microsoft decided, that it’s not a good idea.
For more information see the discussion on the ASP.NET Core issue '[Default middleware for request validation, like IIS has](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/64)'.

That means that validation has to take place on the inbound model. And that in the Razor (.cshtml)
you should output user provided input like `@Model.Content`, which encodes the given string.

Please bear in mind that those escaping techniques might not work when the text that was output is not inside a Html part.

So **don't** use `@Html.Raw(..)` unless you know that the data provided has been sanitized.

Supplement:

- You might want to consider a [Web Application Firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) (WAF)
  for a generic protection against malicious requests (e.g. XSS or SQL Injection).
- For protecting your users against an XSS attack you might also have a look at
  providing a [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) (CSP).

Comment: This makes me incredibly happy. I've been properly encoding data on the client 100% of the time since Razor came out (I made some mistakes back in the <%= %> days), and still fighting with that stupid "Potentially dangerous" nonsense - I could never find all of the various spots where you have to turn it off.