# Where is Request.Unvalidated on asp.net-core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have noticed that in *classic* **ASP.NET MVC** there is an `Unvalidated` property on `Request` which allows Access to raw values provided by the current request.

I cannot identify this property on ASP.NET MVC ***Core***. Is there still a way to Access that information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET Core doesn't have the same request validation feature as it was in ASP.NET. Here are team responses in [GH issue](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/64):

> RequestValidation was always rather porous, and eventually we came to the realisation that validate should be an app concern, because what's validate for one application isn't valid for another,

and

> We have no plans to ever build a request validation middleware like what existed in System.Web.

Also useful: SO [Enable asp.net core request validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061401/enable-asp-net-core-request-validation). If shortly, Model validation should be used instead.