# Protect API from SQL Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating an API the method below gets staff by their name in the query parameter or all staff. However, does the `[FromQuery(Name = "name")]` protect from SQL injection, unsure if this is a default feature of .NET core 2.2?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetStaff([FromQuery(Name = "name")] string firstName)
{
    if (firstName == null)
    {
       //get all staff
       var staff = _repo.GetAllStaff().ToList();
       return Ok(staff);
    }

    if (firstName != null)
    {
       //get staff by firstName
       var staffByName = _repo.GetStaffByName(firstName).ToList();
       return Ok(staffByName);
    }

    return BadRequest("No staff found");
}
```

Method in Repository

```
    public IEnumerable<ApiStaff> GetStaffByName(string name)
    {
        var staffName = _context.ApiStaff.Where(k => k.FirstName == name);
        return staffName;
    }
```

Comment: You are using an ORM. You are fine. As a general rule, unless you are concatenating a string and sending it to the database, you are fine 99% of the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if you are using an ORM such as entity framework, however judging from naming conventions `_context` and the Where linq query, I'd guess you are.

ASP.net Core does not have built in SQL injection prevention as such, in fact [Asp.net core does not have request validation built into it anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061401/enable-asp-net-core-request-validation).

However using an [ORM has some natural SQL injection prevention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations#prevent-sql-injection-attacks):

> LINQ to Entities injection attacks:
>
> Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is
>   performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries,
>   LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation
>   or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL
>   injection attacks.

This is not the case if you chose to execute SQL directly within the ORM, so it depends on how your are using it.

Security should be considered as "defence in depth", adding mitigation techniques at each layer or boundary of your application.

A simple example for your use case could be constraining first name to sensible values, for example no longer than X characters (30?), no numerics etc, however this is easier said than done for [internationalization](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names) therefore even if a weakness is found in Entity Framework, then you are thwarting an attacker by only giving them a limited character set to attack you with.

I'd recommend reading [OWASP's cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet#ASP.NET_MVC_Guidance)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the extra information! Yes, having had a look at my project then entity framework is being used.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of assistance.